# #= require not working after upgrade to Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sprockets, ruby-on-rails-5.2, rails-sprockets, rails-upgrade

I upgraded Rails 4.2.10 application to Rails 5. Solved errors with bundling and some deprecations. I am able to start the Rails Application, but when I try to load the Application, it fails with error, `Invalid CSS after "#": expected id name, was "= require` in the css file

I tried using @import, but it fails for external files in vendor/assets. Nevertheless, I want to understand why it isnt working anymore. In my config, I have the file in `config.assets.precompile +=`

In my index.html.erb,

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'users' %>
```

In users.scss,

```
#= require "dashboard/dx"
```

Note: I am using sass-rails in my Gemfile

The error that I get,

```
Sass::SyntaxError in Dashboard::Users#index
Invalid CSS after "#": expected id name, was "= require "dash..."
Extracted source (around line #1):

#= require "dashboard/dx"
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey I think the error is throwing because in your typical `.scss` file you would have to use either an `@import "dashboard/dx" and`#= require`might only work in`.css`

Answer (score 0):

The problem with this line

```
 #= require "dashboard/dx"
```

This syntax is not working with .scss file. Either You have to write like this

```
@import 'dashboard/dx'
```

Or rename the file with .css extension.

Note: You can also try to rename with .css.scss extension May be it works also sometimes.